# Como hacer un NuGet package compatible con .NET Framework/Standard/Core?

Tags: c#, packages, nuget

He estado haciendo mi paquete NuGet apenas unos dias.

Es este: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelFromList/1.4.0

Internamente utilizo al packete de EPPlus, el cual especifica que es compatible con los 3 estandares y al probarlo es correcto.

Solo que no se como se hace eso.

Esta es la informacion de mi proyecto:

- VS2017
- .NET 3.5
- Uso nuget.exe para crear el paquete NuGet
- Uso archivo .nuspec para crear el paquete (nuget pack <.nuspec file>)
- El unico paquete NuGet que tengo instalado es EPPLus

Este es mi archivo .nuspec:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <id>ExcelFromList</id>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
    <title>ExcelFromList</title>
    <description>Straightforward and easy way to create stylized excel workbooks from lists. Add an image, title, subtitles and overal cell styles/formats. Uses the EPPlus engine.</description>
    <releaseNotes>Succesfully tested on .NET frameworks from 3.5 through 4.8</releaseNotes>
    <authors>Raul Marquez</authors>
    <owners>Raul Marquez</owners>
    <copyright>Copyright 2020 Raul Marquez</copyright>
    <projectUrl>https://github.com/RaulMarquezInclan/ExcelFromList</projectUrl>
    <license type="expression">GPL-3.0-only</license>
    <tags>excel list listtoexcel</tags>

    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="EPPlus" version="5.1.0" />
    </dependencies>

  </metadata>

  <files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\net35\ExcelFromList.dll" target="lib\net35" />
    <file src="bin\Debug\net35\ExcelFromList.xml" target="lib\net35" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Al crear el paquete me arroja este warning:

> WARNING: NU5128: Some target frameworks declared in the dependencies
>   group of the nuspec and the lib/ref folder do not have exact matches
>   in the other location. Consult the list of actions below: - Add a
>   dependency group for .NETFramework3.5 to the nuspec

Pero aun asi no he encontrado problema alguno.

Alguien me puede apuntar el la direccion correcta?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Usas Visual Studio 2017/2019?

Comment: Correcto, VS 2017, actualize el post para reflejar eso

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema bastante molesto y Microsoft ha proporcionado algo de [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu5128).

Una de las soluciones que puedes intentar y que he podido detectar en tu nuspec sería agregar dentro de dependencies lo siguiente:

```
<dependencies>
...
     <group targetFramework=".NetFramework3.5"/>
...
<dependencies>
```